# Grails GORM findAll returns null collection

Tags: grails, grails-orm, findall

Consider the following domain models:

```
class Sales{
    String salesInvoice
    Customer customer
}

class Customer{
    int customerNumber
    String name
}
```

The problem:  I am trying to retrieve all the sales given a customer.  Thus the code:

```
def sales = Sales.findAllByCustomer(Customer.get(params.id))
```

I don't have problem with getting the customer.  But when I use `println sales.dump()` I get something like

```
<java.util.ArrayList@d3a25f8 elementData=[mypackage.Sales : null, mypackage.Sales : null] size=2 modCount=3>
```

If I understand correctly, this means that the query was able to get a list of `Sales` but what I don't quite understand is why is it returning a list of nulls?  I've tried eager fetching but I don't think that will work in this particular problem.  So how to I get a list of non-null `Sales` objects?

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using? Maybe you are running in the changed data binding handling in 2.0.2?

Comment: I'm still using 2.0.0.  How does the new data binding changes affect my code? Do I have to use another syntax or add another configuration somewhere?

Comment: Have a look at the following blogpost describing the changes. http://blog.springsource.org/2012/03/28/secure-data-binding-with-grails/ This feature was default in 2.0.2 but was made non-default in 2.0.3 because of being a breaking change for many production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects you have shown are not NULL, but the `id` of the objects is currently NULL: Each grails domain object has a `toString()` method which will print `${name of the class} : ${id of the instance}`. If you receive outputs, like you have shown, it generally means, that your instances are existing (otherwise a NPE would have been thrown!), however the id is not yet fetched from the DB.

1. I guess you are creating the objects in the code before. You need to flush the context, otherwise id's are not created.
2. You should declare, that your `Sale` belongs to a `Customer`. http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne

BTW: Name you domain classes in singular. So rename `Sales` to `Sale`.

Comment: You're right.  The list is not null.  I guess Grails was trying to retrieve the attribute `id` but my primary key was named `salesInvoice` instead.

As for the naming convention, I know.  Guilty as charged. :)